# simple frequency distribution in MicroStrategy Dashboard?

Tags: frequency, dashboard, microstrategy

this should be an easy question but I cannot solve it...

I have a simple metric, let's say it is called "a", with entries like

```
a = (B,A,A,B,C,A,A)
```

Now what I would like to gain is the frequency of each entry, thus

```
A: 4
B: 2
C: 1
```

Can somebody help me? Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you convert "a" to an attribute, and then use the Row Count metric against it?

Comment: If I'd know how... Can you explain me how to convert it in Dashboard? Or show me a link?

Comment: Which MicroStrategy product are you using? Desktop, or the full enterprise product?

Comment: I use the full product, Version 10.1.0, as web-Surface application (not desktop).

Comment: I solved it now by loading "a" as attribute from the start, and then duplicating it as a metric. But have the strong feeling that there should be a way without workaround.

Comment: It's possible to build a custom group that returns the distinct values of a metric, and then a count could be applied to that. It all depends exactly how you want to use it.

Fundamentally, metrics are divided amongst attributes in MicroStrategy. So, even though it seems counterintuitive, the simplest way to do something like this is often representing the data as both an attribute and a metric.